# Spark filter DataFrames based on common values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have DF1 and DF2. First one has a column "new_id", the second has a column "db_id"

I need to FILTER OUT all the rows from the first DataFrame, where the value of new_id is not in db_id.

```
val new_id = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4)
val db_id = Seq(1, 4, 5, 6, 10)
```

Then I need the rows with new_id == 1 and 4 to stay in df1 and delete the rows with news_id = 2 and 3 since 2 and 3 are not in db_id

There is a ton of questions on DataFrames here. I might have missed this one. Sorry if that is a duplicate.

p.s I am using Scala if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an left-semi jon:

```
import spark.implicits._

val DF1 = Seq(1,3).toDF("new_id")
val DF2 = Seq(1,2).toDF("db_id")


DF1.as("df1").join(DF2.as("df2"),$"df1.new_id"===$"df2.db_id","leftsemi")
.show()

+------+
|new_id|
+------+
|     1|
+------+
```

Comment: actually, I need the opposite thing. I need for 1 remain in df1 and 3 to be filtered out

Comment: @Martee yes, if `new_id` and `db_id` are unambigouos, otherwise you can use the alias-approach