# Filtering Dataframe with predicate pushdown from another dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

How can I push down a filter to a dataframe reading based on another dataframe I have? Basically want to avoid reading the second dataframe entirely and then doing an inner join. Instead I would like to just submit a filter on the reading to filter at source. Even if I use an inner joined wrapped up with the read, the plan doesn't show that it is getting filtered. I feel like there is definitely a better way to set this up. Using Spark 2.x I have this so far but I want to avoid collecting a List as below:

```
//  Don't want to do this collect...too slow
  val idFilter = df1.select("id").distinct().map(r => r.getLong(0)).collect.toList
  val df2: DataFrame = spark.read.format("parquet").load("<path>") 
    .filter($"id".isin(idFilter: _*))
```

Comment: Your thought would lead you to more slowness in the processing as you would have to check each rows while reading.

Comment: without collect, you should to a leftsemi join, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49658868/1138523

Comment: but I'm pretty sure that will first read the entire dataframe first and then do the join. I'm trying to avoid that and push the filter down to source.

Comment: How did you go on with this? I have exact the same problem, join leads to a full table scan, instead of taking the values from the other dataset for filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use predicate pushdown unless you are implementing a DataSource yourself. Predicate Pushdown is a mechanism provided by the Spark Datasources which must be implemented by each Datasources individually.

For file based Datasources there is already a simple mechanism in place based on partitioning on Disk.

consider the following DataFrame:

```
val df = Seq(("test", "day1"), ("test2", "day2")).toDF("data", "day")
```

If we save that DataFrame to disk the following way:

```
df.write.partitionBy("day").save("/tmp/data")
```

The result will be the following folder structure

```
tmp -
     |
     | - data - |
                |
                |--day=day1 -|- part1....parquet
                |            |- part2....parquet
                |
                |--day=day2 -|- part1....parquet
                             |- part2....parquet
```

If you are now using this datasource like this:

```
spark.read.load("/tmp/data").filter($"day" = "day1").show()
```

Spark doesn't even bother loading the data of folder day2 as there is no need for it.

This is one type of predicate pushdown which works for every standard file format spark supports.

A more specific mechanism would be parquet. Parquet is a columnar based file format which means its quit easy to filter out columns. If you have parquet based files with 3 columns `a`, `b`, `c` in a file `/tmp/myparquet.parquet` the following query:

```
spark.read.parquet("/tmp/myparquet.parquet").select("a").show()
```

will result in an internal predicate pushdown where spark is only fetching data for column `a` without reading data for the columns `b` or `c`.

If someone is interested that mechanisms are established by implementing this trait:

```
/**
 * A BaseRelation that can eliminate unneeded columns and filter using selected
 * predicates before producing an RDD containing all matching tuples as Row objects.
 *
 * The actual filter should be the conjunction of all `filters`,
 * i.e. they should be "and" together.
 *
 * The pushed down filters are currently purely an optimization as they will all be evaluated
 * again.  This means it is safe to use them with methods that produce false positives such
 * as filtering partitions based on a bloom filter.
 *
 * @since 1.3.0
 */
@Stable
trait PrunedFilteredScan {
  def buildScan(requiredColumns: Array[String], filters: Array[Filter]): RDD[Row]
}
```

to be found in https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/interfaces.scala